# Same node in multiple kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to find an answer to this question but can't find it clearly in the kubernetes documentation or in any Q/A forums.

I have a kubernetes cluster running with 4 nodes.
Is it possible to create a second cluster that is reusing one or multiple nodes from the previous one ? Or is a node restricted to be in a single kubernetes cluster ?

I'm running the actual cluster with RKE (rancher tool for deploying k8 cluster) and I found [this issue](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/15456) that makes me doubt about that possibility.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: I bet you could do this if you run VM's on the host and register the VM's as the nodes instead of the host itself. Is this a purely theoretical question or is there a specific end goal you're trying to accomplish by using the same node in multiple clusters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible actually. Kubelet running in each node registers the current node with a Kubernetes API Server. There is a heartbeat sent from the kubelet to the Kubernetes API Server. Now if you reconfigure that kubelet and instruct it to register to different Kubernetes API Server this will lead to heartbeat not going to the first Kubernetes API Server and that node will be marked as NotReady in the first Kubernetes API Server.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing the same K8s node for multiple clusters breaks the idea of K8s Node. For this [issue](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/15456) probably Rancher has to warn or handle the exception for duplicate records or race condition while deploying the cattle-system pods.

Why don't you rather go via,creating a new Rancher Project or K8s Namespace where you will get to use the resources from the nodes that are already running K8s elements.

Comment: The reason I can't do that is the cluster needs to be setup differently for windows nodes and I don't want to create another 3 Linux nodes and 3 Windows nodes before moving containers to the new cluster and then deleting the old nodes, it would have been easier to reuse the Linux nodes but it looks like it is not possible.